# Okhttp3 (Android Java) is not reliably returning responses

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, okhttp

I am developing an app in Android Studio (Java) that uses the Google speech recognition API and a certain other API that I am trying to make a POST request to. Here is an excerpt of my code.

```
String url = MY_URL;
String jsonSpeechResults = "{\"prompt\": \"" + speechResults + "\"}";

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(jsonSpeechResults, MediaType.parse("application/json"));
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).addHeader("Authorization", API_KEY).post(body).build();

try  {
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                      
       }

       @Override
       public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
           try {
               String theResponse = response.body().string();
               errorView.setText(theResponse);
           } catch(Exception f) {
               errorView.setText(f.getMessage());
           }

       }
   });
} catch (Exception g) {
   errorView.setText(g.getMessage());
}
```

Here is how this part of the app is supposed to work. When I speak some words, the speech recognition API picks up my words, and when the speech recognition results are returned, those results get sent to my other API (the one that corresponds to MY_URL) in a POST request, and then that API should return some JSON, which is then supposed to print out in string format in the errorView TextView field. If it is not apparent by this explanation, this excerpt of code is inside of the onResults method of a RecognitionListener object that is defined in the onCreate method.

Whenever I run this on my Android phone, I am expecting the response results to appear in my errorView TextView field, but instead all that appears is a single "{". Furthermore, the request doesn't even seem to get made at all the first time I speak into the phone. I have to speak again for the request to even get made (even though I know for certain that the speech recognition does work the first time; it is just the other API that doesn't seem to receive my request the first time I speak).

I don't understand why, and this is annoying me. Furthermore, I can't use

```
client.newCall(request).execute()
```

because this just returns an exception. Even the message from a try catch does not tell me what the problem is.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Is your TextView a single-line textview, and your response has more than one line so the `{` would be the opening brace of a json object with the rest truncated?

Comment: @laalto That helped. I am getting results now. However, there is still the issue that my first set of words don't seem to make the request or return any results.

Comment: That problem is likely somewhere else in your code